# Why is this action running twice?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

This is an action to post a comment. For some reason the comment is being posted twice. When I put a breakpoint, I see when it gets to the bottom of this action, it goes back to the beginning again! I can't figure out why?

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult postComment(string comment, string userId, string workerid)
{
    CleanerManager cm = new CleanerManager("Cleaning_LadyConnectionString");
    CommentsOnUser c = new CommentsOnUser();
    c.Comment = comment;
    c.CleanerId = int.Parse(workerid);
    c.UserId = int.Parse(userId);
    c.Date = DateTime.Today;
    cm.AddCommentOnUser(c);
    return this.RedirectToAction
         ("Profile", new { id = workerid });
}
```

Here is the javascript

```
$(".hiredButton").on('click', function () {
  $("#commentModal").modal();
    $(".postComment").on('click', function () {

        var comment = $("#Message").val();

        var workerId = $(".postComment").data('workerid');
        var userId = $(".postComment").data('userid');


        $.post("/S/postComment", { comment: comment, userId: userId, workerId: workerId }, function () {
            window.location = "http://baltimoresitter.com/S/profile?Id=" + workerId;
        });
    });

});
```

Here is the view

```
       <button type="button" data-workerid="@Model.Cleaner.id" data-userid="@Model.User.id" class="btn btn-default postComment" data-dismiss="modal">Post Comment</button>
```

Comment: It's probably going to be something in your View.

Comment: I think, the problem is in the View or some script.

Comment: are users posting comments on <enter>? it may be due to a client-side event duplication

Comment: Watch your network traffic on the client to verify how many requests are being sent to the server. If you see extra requests, track down what happens when you submit your form to see if anything strange is happening, possibly by double clicking a submit button or some JavaScript that's running extra times. And also, create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)!.

Comment: I added the javascipt, @dlatkay I am testing it. It is not being pressed twice.

Comment: Do you really want to add a handler on the press of another button? Are you sure you're not adding the handler twice?

Comment: ok, thanks for all your help! Seems like I had another javascript file which was also posting a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Each time you click the button another event is being registered onto the ".postComment", so the line

```
$(".postComment").on('click' ...
```

every time runs is registering another function on to the click event and you will see it called more than once.